# Merging global and local scopes

Tags: python

If this works

```
x=5
def main():
    for globe in locals():
        globals().update(locals()[globe])
    print x
main()
```

then why doesn't this?

```
x=5
def main():
    for globe in locals():
        globals().update(locals()[globe])
    x+=1
    print x
main()
```

The error in the latter statement claims that x is referenced before assignment, however it works in the first example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python when you assign a variable the declaration happens automatically.
So when you assign a value to `x` inside the function, python think that is a new local variable, shadowing the global `x`.

if you want to assign a value to the global `x` you can do this:

```
x=5
def main():
    global x

    x += 1
    print x
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a global variable in python without explicitly doing so. By writing `x+=1` you are assigning a value to x and are implicitly declaring x as a local variable. But it is not defined and therefore you get an error.

The loop has no actual effect, as the `locals` dictionary is empty.

If you want to use global variables in Python (which you shouldn't, but that's another matter), you should use the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

suffixing 1 and 2 your two functions, you can find local names (syntax slightly different in python 2) :

```
In [7]: main1.__code__.co_varnames
Out[7]: ('globe',)

In [8]: main2.__code__.co_varnames
Out[8]: ('globe', 'x')
```

So `x` have different status. In the second case the local `x` mask the global one, so x=x+1 cause the error, because not yet defined.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html) :

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as nonlocal or global.(...).If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable.